# @react-native-community/segmented-control fails on iOS. How can I get over this issue?

Tags: react-native, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to create an app with React Native and Expo (latest versions). I want to use [this package](https://github.com/react-native-community/segmented-control), but I get into trouble when I am testing the component on iOs. The package is recommended by react-native official documentation. The main example from git is working perfectly on Android, but on iOS "View config not found for name RNC Segmented Control".

I've created a snack that also reproduces the error here: https://snack.expo.io/@ivy.mihai/94f0cf

Comment: Did you run `pod install` in the ios folder?

Comment: I am using Expo and Windows. I think I don't have to do this. Why do you think it would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually caused by the SDK version that I had used. I've updated the SDK version and it worked on both platforms.